# How is Typeahead's grey input hint achieved?

Tags: html, css, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

[image]

I want to achieve this grey hint effect.

However, when I try to inspect the elements, typeahead loses focus and the hints disappear, making it hard to see what's going on here.

Basically, they have something like this

```
<input class="tt-hint">
<input class="tt-input">
<pre>col</pre>
```

And I can't seem to find anything by searching for "orado" in the DOM tree. I didn't find it in the styles for these three elements, either.

Can someone illustrate how is this effect achieved, maybe by writing an example on jsFiddle? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of the `input.tt-hint` is set to the typeahead suggestion.  It's not being inserted into the DOM, it's setting the `.val()` of it.

The trick is that the `input.tt-hint` is transparent, readonly, and positioned just over the actual input. That's the grey bit, and `typeahead.css:136` defines that grey as `.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {color: #999999;}`.

Meanwhile, there's a `<pre>` that is set to the value of the user's input, placed just over the `input.tt-hint`, in order to show the original color.  That one is actually placed in the DOM, and if you inspect element, you will find, in the above case, "col".

My best suggestion is that, in the future, you should inspect element, make it so you can see the element in the code and the rendered input on the same screen.  Then you can start typing, and see what changes.